# Getting the Foreground Activity of any application in a Service written in other application

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, service, intentservice

What I want is that I need the reference to the current Activity of ANY application that is on the foreground.

Basically I have written a service and I want to get the reference to the "current" foreground activity in that service. 
With "current" I mean any application activity other than the one that has started that service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I want is that I need the reference to the current Activity of ANY application that is on the foreground.

That is not possible. Other applications are running in other processes; you do not have access to Java objects, such as `Activity` instances, in those processes.